# AS3 - Date January-01-2011

Tags: actionscript-3, date

How can I get a date in a format like this out of Flash AS3?

> January-01-2011

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `formatDate()` function I made in the following example to format the date the way you want it:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var date:Date = new Date();

            trace(formatDate(date)); // output: June-02-2011

        }// end function

        private function formatDate(date:Date):String
        {
            var month:String, dateString:String, year:String;

            var months:Array = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

            month = months[date.getMonth() - 1]

            dateString = (date.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + date.getDate().toString() : date.getDate().toString();

            year = date.getFullYear().toString();

            return month + "-" + dateString + "-" + year; 

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Answer (score 0):

create a formatted string using the [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class with an array of strings for each month.  the Date class is a very broad top level class with lots of functionality.  the attached link to the documentation includes sample code.  it's easily tailorable to your needs.

Comment: Is there a native way to get a word like "January" or a day of month with a "0" in front? (Like 01-09)

Comment: i don't think so.  just make your own array of months and call them out by index (iE:  myMonths[0] could be "January")